# How to play Audio from internal storage with encoded string file

Tags: java, android

I want to play a decoded string to audio file.

The string is received from another activity, but `mediaPlayer` shows null. How can I get and set the path in `media.create()`?

```
public class AAudio extends AppCompatActivity {

Button play_audio;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aaudio);
    String recieve_file = getIntent().getStringExtra("audio_file");
    play_audio = findViewById(R.id.textShow);

    byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(recieve_file, 0);
    String fileName = String.valueOf(decoded);
    Log.e("~~~~~~~~ Decoded: ", Arrays.toString(decoded));
    try {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File myDir = new File(root, "/kaushlya/mp3");
        String path = String.valueOf(myDir);
        myDir.mkdirs();

        String audioName = "Advicory.mp3";
        File file = new File(myDir, audioName);
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            os.write(decoded);
            os.close();
            **mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Uri.parse(root)+path+fileName));
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);**
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    play_audio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
}
}
```